# Quiero hacer una url hacia el perfil del usuario con el id node js

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express, routes

Por ejemplo: pagina.com/profiles/:id

lo intenté de esta forma

```
 router.get(`/profiles/:id`), function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'user' });
  const userID = req.session.id;

  const users = connection.query('SELECT * FROM users');

  users.findOne({ where: { id: userID } });

}
```

Comment: ¿Intentaste con  `req.params.id`? ¿Por qué estás poniendo el render al inicio del método? ¿Por qué no usas el resultado de `findOne` ni de ninguna de las consultas que haces? Si usas sequelize como parece ¿Por qué usas `connection.query` y no algo como `findAll`? Tu código no tiene mucho sentido. Es una mezcla extraña de cosas que no se acomplan entre sí.

Comment: es que no sabía como hacerlo e improvisé, ¿Puedes mandarme un codigo de ejemplo?

Answer (score 1):

Primero que todo te recomiendo separar la lógica por rutas y controladores, ahora bien, según lo que veo no haz usado el `params`, haciéndolo con ello te queda de la siguiente forma (siguiendo tu lógica):

```
router.get('/profiles/:id'), function async (req, res, next) {


const { id } = req.params; 
const eResultado = await connection.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1`, {id}); 

res.json(eResultado.rows[0]); 

}
```

En la parte del `res.json` es para que el servidor te retorne el registro en formato JSON; puedes dejarlo así o retornar un `.status` o nada, como tú prefieras.

> Recuerda que se tiene que usar asincronía (async/await) porque la BD nunca deja de operar.

Comment: me sale que await no tiene efecto en este tipo de expresión, ¿Es normal?

Comment: No, es que yo no lo trabajo así normalmente, lo que hago es separar en un controlador la lógica de las rutas; intenta quitarle el `function` y dejarlas como una función de flecha, tal que así: `async (req, res, next) => {  // La lógica que está arriba} `

Comment: Si no te funciona, crea un archivo `.js`, ese será tu controlador así que llámalo algo que lo identifique tal cual. Crea funciones, yo siempre lo hago así `const obtenerEmpleados = async (req, res, next) => { // La lógica que está arriba } `

Comment: Despues de eso, llamo al .js en el archivo de las rutas?

Comment: Sí, tal cual, usas el `import { funcion1, funcion2, funcion 3} from 'Ruta del archivo .js'` y solo dejarías en el archivo de rutas algo como esto: `router.get('/profiles/:id', funcion1); `